# Cypress: why do I need to run cy.wait(0) before each test?

Tags: cypress

I'm testing the following app: https://objective-benz-e53b25.netlify.app/

It's a bootstrap dashboard and I'm just testing clicking on a drop-down menu, then clicking and item, and checking that I'm being redirected.

this is are tests I run:

```
describe('Sapper template app', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        cy.visit('/')
        // cy.wait(0);
    });

    it('has the correct <h1>', () => {
        cy.contains('h1', 'Dashboard')
    });

    it('navigates to /settings', () => {
        cy.get('nav a.dropdown-toggle').click();
        cy.get('nav a.dropdown-item').contains('Settings').click();
        cy.url().should('include', '/settings');
        cy.contains('h3', 'Settings')
    });

    it('navigates to /logout', () => {
        cy.get('nav a.dropdown-toggle').click();
        cy.get('nav a.dropdown-item').contains('Logout').click();
        cy.url().should('include', '/pages/authentication/login');
        cy.contains('h3', 'Login')
    });

});
```

And it gives me the following error:

```
  2 passing (10s)
  1 failing

  1) Sapper template app navigates to /settings:
     CypressError: Timed out retrying: cy.click() failed because this element is not visible:

<a class="dropdown-item" href="settings">Settings</a>

This element <a.dropdown-item> is not visible because its parent <div.dropdown-menu.dropdown-menu-right> has CSS property: display: none
```

If I switched the logout (third) test for the settings (second) test, then the failing one is logout.

I had to add a cy.wait(0) on the beofreEach and it solved it.

The strange thing is that now it is working ok, even with the cy.wait commented out.

I shared the code with a colleague of mine and he had the same trouble.

Any idea why it was failling, and why now it seems to work ok?

Comment: `cy.wait(0);` didn't have an effect on the live site, but switching to Firefox did. Seems to be event related, since in Chrome the `.dropdown-menu-right` never visually appears (it never gets the 'show' class) but in Firefox the event works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Issue is  hapening with cy.get('nav a.dropdown-toggle').click();
 click is not working on User Icon hence the drop down is not visible and test fails. 
One of the solution is to use { force: true }. This option is to disable error checking on drop down click.

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.visit("https://objective-benz-e53b25.netlify.app/");
  });

  it("has the correct <h1>", () => {
    cy.contains("h1", "Dashboard");
  });

  it("navigates to /settings", () => {
    cy.get("nav a.dropdown-toggle").click({ force: true });
    cy.get("nav a.dropdown-item").contains("Settings").click({ force: true });
    cy.url().should("include", "/settings");
    cy.contains("h3", "Settings");
  });

  it("navigates to /logout", () => {
    cy.get("nav a.dropdown-toggle").click({ force: true });
    cy.get("nav a.dropdown-item").contains("Logout").click({ force: true });
    cy.url().should("include", "/pages/authentication/login");
    cy.contains("h3", "Login");
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer, I'll give it a try, do you have any idea why it sometimes work? and why the wait(0) seems to fic it?

Comment: `.click({ force: true })` works because the Settings option is present in the DOM, but note that the click event is not getting through to the app (the functions on the dropdown toggle are not getting called). If you enable code coverage, you will probably find these functions are not covered.